# Can't call JS function from @JavaScript import in Vaadin view

Tags: vaadin, vaadin-flow

I have this Vaadin view:

```
@Route()
@JavaScript(value="scripts/print.js")
public class PrintableView extends BaseView {


    @Override
    public void setParameter(BeforeEvent event, @OptionalParameter String parameter) {
        super.setParameter(event, parameter);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onAttach(AttachEvent attachEvent) {
        UI.getCurrent().getPage().executeJs("printWhenLoaded($0);",".layout");
    }
    

}
```

And the javascript import:

```
function printWhenLoaded(selector) {
  setTimeout(function () {
    var e = document.querySelector(selector);
    if(e && e.innerHTML.length) {
        window.print();
        window.close();
    }
    else printWhenLoaded(selector)
  }, 200)
};
//printWhenLoaded('.layout');
```

The import is loaded sucessfully (eventually) because when I uncomment the last line it works. But  when attempting to call it from the onAttach method I see an error in the browser console that "printWhenLoaded" is not defined.

It seems that at the time of onAttach the JS file has not actually been loaded by the browser.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your problem is that you're not defining the function in the correct scope, not that the file is not getting loaded and available from the `onAttach` method. Easiest way around it would be to define the function in the `window` object:

```
window.printWhenLoaded = function (selector) {
  // ...
}
```

Comment: This worked. It's not very apparent from the documentation that you must manually scope everything like that if you need to reference from the page itself (Though I suppose it's not necessary if the JS is self-contained).

Comment: Is this really a scope problem? In my case it appears to be a symptom of the transpiler renaming functions, and consequently the function being undefined if a call is attempted with its original name. Of course defining a reference to the function a `window` property addresses that problem too, but might not be a preferred solution.

Comment: Resources loaded with @JavaScript should not be transpiled. If you're including them in the frontend bundle, that's a different matter.