# Vaadin: By pressing button specific JavaScript function should be performed and fetch data

Tags: javascript, button, token, vaadin

This is the JavaScript file `test.js`.

```js
    this.register = function(webAuthnRegisterRequest) {

        //some code
        //completely irrelevant

        }
```

I have created a simple web page using the Java framework Vaadin.

```java
@JsModule("test.js")
public class TestPage extends Composite<VerticalLayout> {

    private Button buttonPrimary0 = new Button();
    
    public TestPage() {

            buttonPrimary0.setText("Create token");
            buttonPrimary0.setWidthFull();
            buttonPrimary0.addThemeVariants(ButtonVariant.LUMO_PRIMARY);
            layoutColumn2.add(buttonPrimary0);
            buttonPrimary0.addClickListener(e -> {
                    UI.getCurrent().getPage().executeJs("register");
                });
        }
}
```

As you can see above, I have used the annotation `@JsModule("test.js")` to link
the JavaScript file with my Vaadin project.

[image: This is my web page.]

Normally, the JavaScript function should fetch some server-side data.

Pressing the button has no effect. Nothing happens.

What is wrong with my code?

Comment: I don't have much hands-on experience with javascript inside vaadin, but I do believe that any function should be defined in the `window` scope (`window.register = function(..){..}`). Additionally, I believe you are missing a parameter when calling the function. Warning: the parameter types are heavily restricted (see https://vaadin.com/docs/v14/flow/browser/tutorial-execute-javascript). related SO post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76155012/3441504